# how to change uint8_t array to a number

Tags: c

I want to change a `uint8_t` array type to a `int` or `string` type, so i can write it in a text file.
for example array:

`uint8_t outstr[4]; \\ outstr is 0x00 0x04 0x49 0xba`

i tried using this code:

`fprintf(ptr_myfile, "%d   \n", *outstr);`

this code give me only the first number '0' ,but I need the all array.
the expected result of the hex number `0x000449ba` should be `281018`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array size is always 4 you could create a `uint32_t` variable:

```
uint32_t num = 0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    num <<= 8;
    num |= outstr[i];
}

fprintf(ptr_myfile, "%" PRIu32 "\n", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

two another ways:

```
typedef union
{
    uint32_t u32;
    uint8_t u8[4];
}u32_t;

int main()
{
    u32_t u32u;
    uint32_t u32;

    /* -----------------------*/

    memcpy(&u32, outstr, sizeof(u32));
    printf("%u", u32);


    /* -----------------------*/

    //you can also use a loop
    u32u.u8[0] = outstr[0];
    u32u.u8[1] = outstr[1];
    u32u.u8[2] = outstr[2];
    u32u.u8[3] = outstr[3];

    printf("%u", u32u.u32);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that the result here depends on the endianness of the system.